# How to prove this convergence in probability property?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

How to prove if $X_n$ converges in probability to $X$ then there exists at least one subsequences converge almost surely to $X$?

I have no idea how to proceed.